# setInterval on my Doughnut.js

Tags: chart.js

Hello to all the team and everyone, 
I want to repeat the animation of the animation of Doughnut.js every 5 seconds. when refreshing  it only load itself once.
this is the Doughnut.js and the content is :

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["California", "Utah", "Texas", "Nevada", "Oregon"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Users",
                backgroundColor: ["#042d48", "#4e9ba5", "#07775f", "#865d52", "#961107"],
                data: [100, 200, 250, 300, 120]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Predicted USers'
        }
    }
});
```

i tried to animate by this :

```
Chart();
setInterval(Chart(), 5000);
```

I am still learning Javascript so a little unsure as to if I am referencing the correct function and where to place the setInterval code.

The animation can be viewed at the bottom of this website: https://www.chartjs.org/

Many thanks for any guidance and direction!

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you are using setinterval wrong.

```
setInterval(someFunction, 5000)
```

not

```
setInterval(someFunction(), 5000)
```

Your current code calls the function once. The setinterval call is doing nothing every 5 seconds.